# Using flashlight cancels SensorListener and accelerometer

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors, flashlight

I'm developing an application where if the screen of the phone is facing up the flashlight starts blinking. If the screen of the phone is facing downwards the flashlight is suppose to stop blinking. For detecting whether if the screen of the phone is facing up or down I'm using the accelerometer. The code to detect the orientation of the screen is here:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        smAccelerometer.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        smAccelerometer.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        int type = event.sensor.getType();
        if (type == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            float gz = event.values[2];
            if (mGZ == 0) {
                mGZ = gz;
            } else {
                if ((mGZ * gz) < 0) {
                    mEventCountSinceGZChanged++;
                    if (mEventCountSinceGZChanged == MAX_COUNT_GZ_CHANGE) {
                        mGZ = gz;
                        mEventCountSinceGZChanged = 0;
                        if (gz > 0) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "now screen is facing up.");
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.show();
                            flashlightFrequency();
                        } else if (gz < 0) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "now screen is facing down.");
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.show();


                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (mEventCountSinceGZChanged > 0) {
                        mGZ = gz;
                        mEventCountSinceGZChanged = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
```

As you can see from this code, whenever the screen is facing up i call the method `flashlightFrequency()` which turns the flashlight on and off in intervals:

```
public void flashlightFrequency() {
        String myString = "0101010101";
        int frequency = 2000; //Delay in ms
        CameraManager camManager;
        String cameraId = null; // Usually front camera is at 0 position.

        camManager = (CameraManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            cameraId = camManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= myString.length(); i++) {
                if (i == myString.length()) {
                    flashlightFrequency();
                }

                if (myString.charAt(i) == '0') {
                    try {
                        camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(frequency);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The accelerometer works fine and I'm able to detect the orientation of the screen **UNTIL** I call the method `flashlightFrequency()`. When the flashlight starts the phone no longer registers motions. It seems like the flashlight cancels the `SensorListener`. Whenever the flashlight is turned on I can't use the accelerometer to detect the orientation of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to implement the `flashlightFrequency()` in an IntentService class. By doing that the flashlight will run in the background and therefore not interfere with the accelerometer.